# Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1

Tags: ruby, gemfile

I’ve upgraded my Ruby version from 2.3.4 to 2.5.1 and now I get an error message when I attempt to bundle install or rails generate my project:

Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1

version info is:

```
C:\RubyDevKit\projects\skit_interchange>ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]
```

I updated Ruby to 2.5.1 because Heroku indicated that my current installed version was no longer supported.

Comment: What is the result of `ruby -v`? `2.3.3`, by any chance? How are you managing the ruby version? `rbenv`? `rvm`? Something else? You need to switch to ruby version `2.5.1`.

Comment: C:\RubyDevKit\projects\skit_interchange>ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: First of all, how did you upgrade the ruby? Did you run system wide update on gems? Were maybe some files left behind? 
If it is not too much of a hassle for you, I would completely reinstall ruby and make sure all the files are gone.

Comment: I updated ruby via https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Comment: Have you uninstalled the prior version?

Comment: Yes; then it stopped running Ruby altogether. I'ts all over the floor at this point. I'm uninstalling everything and starting from scratch....

Comment: Is there any way I can reproduce your problem? It sounds like your local environment got messed up, but I have no idea how. The fact that `ruby -v` returns `2.5.1`, yet `bundle` thinks you're running `2.3.3`, should never happen. Possibly your `$PATH` was messed up, and pointing to the wrong ruby folder? (Side note: Your question also mentions ruby `2.3.4`, but I presume that's a typo.)